# how to determine vSphere virtual machine name from guest OS?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, api

Is there any way to determine the vSphere virtual machine ID or name or UUID from a linux guest?  I have administrative access to the guest, and would like to coordinate some maintenance actions between the guest and vCenter via the vCenter API.  To use the vCenter API, I need to identify which VM I'm operating on.

For one-off operations I can find the VM's information from the vCenter GUI or API because I can interpret the VM naming convention, but I'd like to be able to script these operations starting from the guest OS.  Basically, given a guest VM: determine the vSphere ID of the VM from the guest, then use that ID to manipulate the VM via the vCenter API.

I read that there is a way to cron a script on each hypervisor host to set  guestinfo variables on each running guest which would then be accessible from the guest via open-vm-tools.  It might be difficult for me to get admin access to the hypervisor hosts themselves to install such a script, hence my hope that their may be a more generic way.

Comment: I have admin access to both, which is why I can find the VM name (I can correlate the VM naming convention with the hostname convention, but it's not an exact science) for one-off tasks.  I need to automate these tasks, and my starting point is guest access.

Comment: I should clarify - I have admin access to both in our labs, but less than full admin access to vCenter in production.  I only have vCenter API permissions to do what I need to do, but not to install scripts on the hypervisor hosts.

Answer (score 1):

We found a way to do it.

On the guest:

```
#dmidecode -s system-serial-number
VMware-42 39 51 fb 85 54 7c 91-ac 25 e0 d5 f7 6b 13 b2
```

This serial number is vCenter's "BIOS UUID" for the guest VM, albeit in a slightly different format:

```
Bios UUID     :  423951fb-8554-7c91-ac25-e0d5f76b13b2
```